# Вёрстка сайта

Tags: вёрстка, html, css

Как сделать такую вёрстку сайта, чтобы при изменении (уменьшении) размеров окна браузера, просто появлялись полосы прокрутки и сайт становился не весь виден, но никак не менялся? 
Нужно поправить сайт, который при уменьшении окна почему-то весь "сжимается", съезжаются все элементы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body>
<div style="min-width: 1024px">
Контент сайта.
</div>
</body>
```

Либо вообще указать жестко. `width: 1024px`

Comment: Вууху, спасибо большое. @knes няшка ^^

Answer (score 2):

Удивительно )) Обычно народ ищет пути сделать сайт адаптивным.

Задаёте "обёртке" минимальный размер и ставите overflow: auto; для body

Comment: Так сказал заказчик. А делать "адаптивную" - это уж я не умею, я не верстальщик.  По крайней мере, так лучше, чем разваливаться.